# How to drawing shapes using XLSXWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I wana draw some simple shapes in excel file like as "arrow, line, rectangle, oval" using XLSXWriter, but i can find any example to do it. Is it possible ? If not, what library of python can do that ?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/107

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i wana draw arrow, line.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible?

Unfortunately not. Shapes aren't supported in XlsxWriter, apart from Textbox.

Comment: So what library can do that, please tell me. i want to draw sequence diagram in excel file.